# Let $x,y$ be numbers and $xy = 1$, show that $x$ and $y$ are never zero

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Note: If this question has already been asked my apologies but please indicate the post that has the answer. I checked math.stackexchange but did not find anything. Here was I have so far in term of formal proof:

$xy = 1$ so the product $xy$ is not zero and its inverse exists. Therefore, we can write:

$(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1} x^{-1} = 1^{-1} = 1$

With $1$ the identity such that $x1 = 1x = x$, we have that by right-multiplying the above equation by $x$ we obtain that:

$y^{-1} x^{-1} x = 1x= x$

and

$y^{-1} 1 = y^{-1}= x$.

I am not sure what should be the next step. This is where I need help.

Can we substitute for $x$ in $xy =1$, $x=y^{-1}$ to get $y^{-1} y =1$? This would show that $y$ is a non-zero number because when multiplied by its inverse $y^{-1}$ we get the identity 1. Therefore $y^{-1}$ is a non-zero number and so is $x$.

Comment: Note that $0 \cdot x = y \cdot 0 = 0$ for all $x,y$. Hence if $x \cdot y =1 $ then neither $x$ nor $y$ can be $0$.

Comment: Yes I am working in the field of real number. I should have indicated that. I agree with the comment of copper.hat but is this consider enough to be a formal proof? I do not know, I am learning, I just want to ckeck.

Comment: Of course it is a formal proof. It is an indirect proof, or a proof my contradiction, by showing that the negation of what you want to prove leads to an absurd conclusion (in this case, that $0=xy=1$).

Comment: Thanks user496634, with your comment the answer to my question is complete.

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is wrong.

Firstly, I don't see how you got $(x.y)^{-1} = 1$. How is $(x.y)^{-1}= ((y)^{-1}).((x)^{-1}) $ and then how do you conclude it is $1$? Are you using some unstated axioms ?

Now, substituting $x=y^{-1}$ in $x.y=1$ is correct, **but** $y.y^{-1}=1$ does not allow you to conclude that $y \neq 0$ .

In fact your **actual error** is that you assumed that  the inverses of $x$ and $y$ exist. In reality, for the inverses to exist we should already have $x, y \neq 0$, which happens to be what we set out to prove in the first place. You have erroneously assumed a consequence of the very thing you set out to prove.

See correct proof below.

---

### Axioms -

**A.1** Field  axioms of $\mathbb{R}$.

**A.2** Order properties of $\mathbb{R}$

**A.3** Completeness property of $\mathbb{R}$

### Proof -

#### Given -

$ ( x. y) =1 $, $ x, y \ in \mathbb{R} $

#### Claim -

$ x, y \neq 0 $

### Lemma -

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a.0= 0.a=0$

#### Method 1 -  (Direct Formal proof)

We have,

$a + a.0 = a.1 + a.0= a.(1+0)=a.1=a$

From the first and last equalities -

$a+ a.0=a$

Therefore, $a.0=0$

#### Method 2 -  ( Proof by contradiction )

Assume to the contrary that $a.0\neq 0$.

Then,

there exists $b\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R} : a.0=b$.

We have 2 cases -

Case 1 -. $a\neq 0 $

Then,we can write -

$({1 \over a})(a.0)=(1/a).b$ as $a^{-1}={1\over a}$ exists.

$\Rightarrow ({1\over a}.a).0= (1/a.b)$   ( By associativity of multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$)

$\Rightarrow 1.0={b\over a}$     ( By reciprocal property $\forall a\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R})

$\Rightarrow 0= {b \over a} $    (By definition of $1$)

i.e. we have -

$ 0={b\over a}; b, a \neq 0; b, a \in \mathbb{R}$

Now, consider some $ c \in \mathbb{R}$.

By definition of $0$-

$c+0=c$

$\Rightarrow c+{ b \over a}= c$

$\Rightarrow {(c.a + b)\over a}=c$

$ \Rightarrow c.a+ b=c. a$    ( Since, $a\neq 0$)

$\Rightarrow (c.a + b) + (-c.a) = ca+(-ca)$

$\Rightarrow b=0$    (By definition of $0$ and existence of negative elements)

Which is a contradiction to $b\neq0$.

Case 2 - $a=0$

Then, $a.0=0.0=0$ (Since if the product was non-zero we would have the absurdity $a\gt 0$ and $a=0$ for positive and $a\lt 0$ and $a=0$ for negative $a$. By order property of $\mathbb{R}$)

But$a.0=b$

$\Rightarrow b=0$

Again this is a contradiction to $b\neq  0$.

Therefore our assumption is false and $b=a.0=0$.

Similarly, $0.a=0$ can be proved.

### Solution -

We have,

(x.y)=1.

If $x=0$ , then by Lemma $x.y=0$. But $x.y\neq 0$. Hence $ x\neq 0$.

Similarly, $y\neq 0$.

We see that the proof is complete.

**Q.E.D.**

---

## Notes -

1. We can use proof by contradiction(reductio ad absurdum) by noticing that $0=(x.y)=1$, as noted in the comments by @user496634. In fact, this is actually what we have done, only by contrapositive.
2. Notice that we do not need the Completeness property for this proof, which is a good thing since it allows us to prove the statement for non-complete fields, such as the set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers.
3. Note that we only use the order property once - in Case 2 of the second proof of our lemma. Since the lemma can be proved using method 1 without any need for the order property, it follows that the result is also true for unordered fields, such as the set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers.

Comment: Perhaps in the proof of the Lemma, the second last equality should be $a\cdot(1+0) = a\cdot1$ instead of $a\cdot(1+0)=a\cdot2$. Unless there is something I do not see. I have learned a lot from this proof.

Comment: Also, in Method 2, Case 1 $a \cdot 0 \neq 0$ is assumed but actually the proof is for $0\cdot a \neq 0$. With this correction, the rest is fine except the last sentence that should read "Similarly, $a \cdot 0 = 0$ can be proved".

Comment: @Rene Girard   Yes. The $2$ in the Lemma was a typo. Also, method 1 now proves $a.0\neq 0$ as it should. Fingers seem to develope their own ideas about math while typing on a 4-inch screen ;D .

Comment: At the very starting of your answer, you discard OP's assumptions. But, I have something to mention. We are working in the field of $\mathbb{R}$, $1$ being the multiplicative identity of the commutative group $\mathbb{R}^*$. For the part, where you refute the claim $(x.y)^{-1}= y^{-1}.x^{-1}$, I say the following. From the definition of field, every non zero element has a multiplicative inverse element in it. The product $x.y$ w.r.t the binary operation $.$, the value is non zero, ensuring the existence of its inverse. Hence the claim $(x.y)^{-1}=1$ is perfectly valid.

Comment: As $x.y=1 (≠0) \in \mathbb{R}^*$, and $\mathbb{R}^*$ being a group, the next argument, $(x.y)^-1= y^{-1}.x^{-1}$ holds perfectly. All of these arguments are according to the axioms of field. I don't see any logical error anywhere. Would you mind checking it out?!

Comment: @Subhasis Biswas  I never said that $(x.y)$ does not have a multiplicative inverse. However , while $x$ and $y$ undoubtedly have multiplicative inverses (being non-zero); *here we are attempting to price that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero.* You may be aware that assuming that something is true cannot be used to imply that it is true (except by contradiction).

Comment: Of course, you cannot use the very statement which you want to prove in your proof as an argument.

Comment: But we are in the proof considering the "z=PRODUCT=x.y", not individual $x$ and $y$ .

Comment: Which, I believe is perfect, as long as we don't take for granted that "x" and "y" is non-zero. We cannot do that.

Comment: @Subhasis Precisely, therefore the statement you cite is a logical error. While the statement us true, that is so only when we know that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. This is where your proof comes in. For a group $x, y \in G$ does imply that $xy \in G$. But we CANNOT conclude directly the reverse, which is the error apparently in OP's proof.

Comment: @Subhasis Also, I have not simply discarded OP's assumptions in the manner you state. I have pointed out the flaw in his approach and attempted to help him by demonstrating the correct one. That is the whole point of this site. Your way of putting it is a bit impolite, to say the least.

Comment: The whole point of the discussion is to better our understanding of the subject. I do apologize if I have been rude.

Comment: I also noticed where I went wrong. $(x.y)^{-1}=y^{-1}.x^{-1}$ holds only when we know for sure that $y$ and $x$ are non zero. +1

Comment: @Subhasis Apology accepted. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82250/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-devashishkaushik).